# How to set 6 physical, 6 hyper threading total 12 cores to hyper-v virtual machine - A parameter cannot be found HwThreadCountPerCore

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v, hypervisor

I have windows server 2012 R2 on physical dedicated server

I have created a virtual machine via  Hyper-V  and installed Windows server 2019 in it

My dedicated physical server has 12+12 total 24 cores

12 core is physical and 12 core is hyper threading

From dedicated server's hyper-v interface, there is no option to set how many physical cores and how many logical cores for the created virtual machine

So I am trying to set number of threads per core via the command below from powershell (running as administrator) in the dedicated physical server

`Set-VMProcessor -VMName aa -HwThreadCountPerCore 2`  //aa is the name of hyper v machine

However this command is giving the below error but it should work

What is the error and why it is not working?

How can i set X amount of physical cores and Y amount of logical cores?

```
    Set-VMProcessor : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'HwThreadCountPerCore'.
At line:1 char:28
+ Set-VMProcessor -VMName aa -HwThreadCountPerCore 2
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-VMProcessor], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.SetVMProcessorCommand
```

This command has worked on my personal computer which is Windows 10

Comment: 2012 is a lot older then what you have in 2016.  It doesn't have some of the functionality in newer releases. Have you considered upgrading the Hyper-V host to 2016, or even 2019?

Comment: 2012R2 https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmprocessor?view=winserver2012r2-ps